# Add ''physics.addBody'' local imgpath lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

**Solved by adding**

```
if ( temp.imgpath == "badcloud.png" ) then
  physics.addBody( randomcloud, "static", { density=.1, bounce=.1, friction=.2, radius=45 } )
end
```

============================================================================

I'd like to add a **`physics.addBody`** to *cloud4* so it can interact with a `Runtime:addEventListener("collision", onCollision)` but if i do this:

```
local cloud4 = {}
physics.addBody(cloud4, "static", {densit=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=45})
cloud4.imgpath = "badcloud.png";
cloud4.movementSpeed = 18000;
table.insert(cloudTable, cloud4);
```

I get a bad argument error, how can i resolve this ?

```
function initcloud()
    local cloud1 = {}
    cloud1.imgpath = "cloud1.png"; --Set Image Path for cloud
    cloud1.movementSpeed = 10000; --Determines the movement speed of cloud
    table.insert(cloudTable, cloud1); --Insert cloud into cloudTable

    local cloud2 = {}
    cloud2.imgpath = "cloud2.png";
    cloud2.movementSpeed = 12000;
    table.insert(cloudTable, cloud2);               

    local cloud3 = {}
    cloud3.imgpath = "cloud3.png";
    cloud3.movementSpeed = 14000;
    table.insert(cloudTable, cloud3);

    local cloud4 = {}
    cloud4.imgpath = "badcloud.png";
    cloud4.movementSpeed = 18000;
    table.insert(cloudTable, cloud4);   

    local cloud5 = {}
    cloud5.imgpath = "cloud5.png";
    cloud5.movementSpeed = 21000;
    table.insert(cloudTable, cloud5);
end --END initcloud()
```

---

the full code

```
function createClouds()
function initcloud()
    local cloud1 = {}
    cloud1.imgpath = "cloud1.png"; --Set Image Path for cloud
    cloud1.movementSpeed = 10000; --Determines the movement speed of cloud
    table.insert(cloudTable, cloud1); --Insert cloud into cloudTable

    local cloud2 = {}
    cloud2.imgpath = "cloud2.png";
    cloud2.movementSpeed = 12000;
    table.insert(cloudTable, cloud2);               

    local cloud3 = {}
    cloud3.imgpath = "cloud3.png";
    cloud3.movementSpeed = 14000;
    table.insert(cloudTable, cloud3);

    local cloud4 = {}
    cloud4.imgpath = "badcloud.png";
    cloud4.movementSpeed = 18000;
    table.insert(cloudTable, cloud4);   

    local cloud5 = {}
    cloud5.imgpath = "cloud5.png";
    cloud5.movementSpeed = 21000;
    table.insert(cloudTable, cloud5);


end --END initcloud()   

function getRandomcloud()
local temp = cloudTable[math.random(1, #cloudTable)] -- Get a random cloud from cloudTable
local randomcloud = display.newImage(temp.imgpath);
randomcloud.myName = "cloud";
randomcloud.movementSpeed = temp.movementSpeed; -- set the cloud cloudting point
randomcloud.x = math.random(10, _W);
randomcloud.y = -35;
randomcloud.rotation = math.random(0, 20); -- move the cloud
cloudMove = transition.to(randomcloud, {
time = randomcloud.movementSpeed, 
y = 500,
onComplete = function(self)
self.parent:remove(self);
self = nil;
end 
});
end

function cloudtGame()
    cloudTimer1 = timer.performWithDelay(3000,getRandomcloud, 5)
    cloudTimer2 = timer.performWithDelay(2000,getRandomcloud, 0)
    cloudTimer3 = timer.performWithDelay(2400,getRandomcloud, 0)    
    cloudTimer4 = timer.performWithDelay(7000,getRandomcloud, 0)    
    cloudTimer5 = timer.performWithDelay(9000,getRandomcloud, 0)        
end--END cloudtGame()
initcloud()
cloudtGame()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
physics.addBody(cloud4, "static", {densit=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=45})
```

has a typo in it, leading to the error. It should be `density` and not `densit`. Like this:

```
physics.addBody( cloud4, "static", { density = .1, bounce = 0.1, friction = .2, radius = 45 } )
```

Comment: bad argument #-1 to 'addBody'

Comment: Doesn't the object require `x` and `y` values? Add `cloud4.x = 0` and `cloud4.y = 0` before `physics.addBody()` call.

Comment: x and y values are based in: function getRandomcloud(). randomcloud.x = math.random(10, _W);
randomcloud.y = -35;

Comment: And where have you called it?

Comment: @kevinver You are calling the addBody before its `x` and `y` values can be assigned..

Comment: i can do the addBoddy in 'function getRandomcloud()' for 'physics.addBody( randomcloud,...' but i only what it to be for cloud4

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24376/discussion-between-back-in-a-flash-and-kevin-ver)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding

```
if ( temp.imgpath == "badcloud.png" ) then
  physics.addBody( randomcloud, "static", { density=.1, bounce=.1, friction=.2, radius=45 } )
end
```